# How to set max number of items in a list?

Tags: list, flutter, max

I have containers which user can tab to choose their interests.

Upon tabbing, container color changes to show users they have chosen this option, and the interest is added to a list (backend).

Currently, everything is functioning well, but I don't want users to choose more than 9 interests bcos those interests will probably not be as important anymore.

Anyone has any idea how can I limit the max number of items in my list? As well as not allowing users to tab on the 10th container, or maybe at any point of time only 9 containers will change color.

Any guidance is much appreciated! Stay safe all! :D

Below is the code where the interests are added or removed.

```
    var chosenInterests = chosenSportsInterests +
        chosenEntertainmentInterests +
        chosenCharacterInterests +
        chosenArtsInterests +
        chosenWellnessInterests +
        chosenLanguageInterests;

    if (widget.viewInterest.isChosen) {
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Container container = Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.024,
            vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.003),
        // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 6, 12, 6),
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4.5, 3, 6, 3),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: widget.viewInterest.isChosen && chosenInterests.length < 9
              ? Colors.yellow[300]
              : Color(0xff04072E),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
              spreadRadius: 2,
              blurRadius: 1,
              offset: Offset(0, 1), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
        child: Text(
          '${widget.viewInterest.title}',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: widget.viewInterest.isChosen && chosenInterests.length < 9
                  ? Colors.black
                  : Colors.white),
        ));

    if (widget.viewInterest.isChosen && chosenInterests.length < 9) {
      chosenSportsInterests.add('${widget.viewInterest.title}');
      print(chosenInterests);
    } else {
      chosenSportsInterests.remove('${widget.viewInterest.title}');

      print(chosenInterests);
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you add code on how you store those interest and how you add new interest to the list.

Comment: hi Mkobuolys, I've added my code, lmk what you think. :D

Comment: Just check `chosenInterests.length` before adding a new interest. If the length is 9, you should not allow adding more interests.

Comment: I've added the code (as seen in updated code above), but the 10th interest & beyond are still being added to the list. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a list and each time your user chooses an interest you add it to that list.
with this thing what you can do is whenever your user choose an interest before adding to the list check that list length and if it was larger than 9 you can show a message instead of adding to list

Comment: I've added the code (as seen in updated code above), but the 10th interest & beyond are still being added to the list. Is there something wrong with my code?